# How can I click on button only in specific div in Selenium?

Tags: testing, xpath, selenium

I have 3 divs. Every one contains a button. Every button in every `div` has the same XPath:

```
//*[@id='variant_selector']/div/div[2]/div[3]/span
```

The XPaths for the `div`'s are different:

```
//*[@id='product_sets']/div[1],
//*[@id='product_sets']/div[2],
//*[@id='product_sets']/div[3]
```

How can I click for example the button in `div` 2 using Selenium?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you need to post the html to be sure, but doesn't combining the two work?

```
//*[@id='product_sets']/div[2]//*[@id='variant_selector']/div/div[2]/div[3]/span
```

This is the div XPath first, followed by the XPath for selecting the button inside the div.